# Fix Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 16.04 when getting the "Stopping User Manager for UID 121" error

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, uid

OS: **Ubuntu** *(Gnome)* **16.04**
**NOTE:** *This does only seem to affect (as far as I know) **Nvidia** GPU users.*

*Issue:*
When booting you see your screen for no more than a few seconds and then it seems to "restart" and repeat itself. The message on the screen for a brief moment is "**Stopping User Manager for UID 121**".

*Result:*
I had this issue and determined that it was the ***Nvidia drivers***. For some reason they did not take well with an Ubuntu update. During the update one of the things updated was **xorg** and **linux-headers**; I think it is possible that one of these is to blame. However, instead of laying blame, I would rather find a solution, which I seem to have. Here is what I did.

*Solution:* (I think)

1. Booted into GRUB.
2. **GRUB:** *Selected* **Advanced options for Ubuntu**
3. **GRUB:** *Selected* latest recovery module. *("Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-43-generic (recovery mode)")*
4. **Recovery Menu:** *Selected* **networking**. (To enable network access)
5. **Recovery Menu:** *Selected* **dpkg**. (To attempt to update any needed packages)
6. **Recovery Menu:** *Selected* **root**. (Get root access)
7. You need to determine in what directory you want to download a new driver file.
8. **cd** <*to_prefered_directory*>
9. **wget** <*NVIDIA_driver_URL*> **(See URL below)**
10. **chmod a+x** <*NVIDIA_driver_FILE*>
11. **./**<*NVIDIA_driver_FILE*>
12. Follow the prompt. If you are running a 64-bit system. Ignore the 32-bit warning.

***Nvidia 367.57 Driver URL:***
**367.57 Drivers:**
http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/367.57/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.57.run
**375.26 Drivers:**
http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/375.26/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.26.run

---

That's it. You should be able to reboot your system and select your **Ubuntu** installation and boot like normal. I did notice a slightly slower response when starting back up. But once that was done it ran like a champ again.

**PS:** If you are experiencing this issue over again. Try to update your system while you are in it. If that does not work try these instructions for a second time. I have found that sometimes repeating these steps works. I also found that sometimes it takes a moment for the update (if any) actually take affect.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly simpler solution: I found that using `lightdm` the `nomodeset` parameter was the key to fixing my issue with 18.04

#### Nomodeset: How to get in once via temporary grub change

You can add the grub configuration parameters if you hold right `shift` at bootup and press `e` to edit Ubuntu parameters.  You need to replace `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`.  Then hit `ctrl x` to save and continue.

#### Lightdm: How to put in the permanent fix

Once in, open a terminal and type
`sudo apt install lightdm`, then
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, then
`sudo reboot`

Please refer to this amazing guide for more details and screenshots!:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Getting failed to fetch `http:......`